# How could I schedule a backup and then export it on a remote server (without a pw) by using cron job?

Tags: ssh, cron, backup, scp, remote

I need to schedule a backup (at a certain time) and set an automatic export to a remote server (without using a pw) with **scp** command. How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Split the problem into three parts. 1 how to take a backup, 2 how to schedule this at a particular time, 3 how to get the result onto a remote system. Which parts have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to setup an SSH key pair and use that to automate the authentication process.

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/